# depth' is 6 (cv_64f) cvtcolor does not work

Tags: python, scikit-image

```
from skimage import data
from skimage import exposure
from skimage.exposure import adjust_log, equalize_adapthist

#foto di referenza
image_ref = cv2.imread("../Reference images/IMG_1807.jpg")
image_ref = cv2.resize(image_ref,(1080, 1080))
image_ref = cv2.cvtColor(image_ref, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

matched = equalize_adapthist(image_1)
matched = adjust_log(matched)

cv2.imwrite("prova_clahe_1.jpeg", cv2.cvtColor(matched_1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

I tried to convert into float32, but it does not work

#This does not work

```
#cv2.imwrite("prova_clahe_5.jpeg", cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(matched_1), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Comment: Your question seems to be about errors trying to save a float image with **OpenCV**. I don't understand why you are tagging with `scikit-image` or showing any `scikit-image` code. Surely you can tag `OpenCV` and create a dummy representative image?

Answer (score 0):

The `matched_1` image variable is of `float` data type. You cannot convert it to RGB color arrangement unless you first convert the image to an `integer` data type.

OpenCV allows you to do this using `cv2.normalize()` function. Just mention the lowest and highest pixel intensities; also mention the data type:

```
dst = cv2.normalize(matched, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)`
```

Now you can convert the variable `dst` to any color space and also save it using `cv2.imwrite()`